# post to subscribers' walls automatically

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I need a wordpress plugin to automatically post every article to a facebook fan page I own.

==old question==

In my wordpress blog I'd like a "subscribe with facebook" button that lets a user subscribe to my posts, so that they appear on their profile on facebook (something like an RSS subscription..)

Is there anything like this? How could I do something similar in wordpress easily?

Maybe we could find a way to automatically post new articles to a facebook fan page, and then users could easily subscribe to that fan page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

All of what you describe is technically possible, although you do run a risk of running afoul of Facebook Platform Policy violations which will get your app shut down by Facebook.

The approach of posting to a fan page is much safer from a policy perspective.

I recommend a close reading of the Platform Policies section IV at https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

To post to the wall you will need the offline_access and publish_stream extended permissions.

I do not know if there is a WordPress plugin for this already or if you need to whip one up yourself.

Comment: i see, posting to a fan page would be fine the.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if there is anything like this, and [RSS Graffiti](http://apps.facebook.com/rssgraffiti/) seems to be what you are looking for.

If you want to roll your own, you can write to your Page feed using the Graph API. It is more work than it seems at first though, as you have to keep the oauth token updated (it can change even if it is long lasting, for example when you change your Facebook password), take care of getting correct permissions etc.